# Classes for Questions and Answers

Tags: java, beginner, quiz

I made a simple Question "system":

**Answer**

Stores an answer (string) and a boolean value to check if the answer is correct or not.

```
public class Answer {

    private String answer;
    private boolean isCorrect;

    public Answer(String answer, boolean isCorrect) {
        this.answer = answer;
        this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return isCorrect;
    }

}
```

**Question**

I don't know if I should use "Answer[] answers" or "Answers... answers" in the Question constructor.

```
public class Question {

    private String question;
    private Answer[] answers;

    public Question(String question, Answer... answers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public Answer[] getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
        for(Answer tempAnswer : answers)
            if(tempAnswer.getAnswer().equals(answer) && tempAnswer.isCorrect())
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isCorrectIgnoreCase(String answer) {
        for(Answer tempAnswer : answers)
            if(tempAnswer.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && tempAnswer.isCorrect())
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

**SAMPLE**

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question questionA = new Question("Do chickens fly?",
                                          new Answer("Yes", true),
                                          new Answer("No", false));
        System.out.println(questionA.getQuestion());

        while(true) {
            if(questionA.isCorrectIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine()))
                break;
            else
                System.out.println("No, that is incorrect. Please try again.");
        }

        System.out.println("Correct.");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Vicente. You have quite a good question for a beginner. I hope you get some fine answers.

Comment: You can see my similar database version of this at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5858666/631619  The comments may also help you with some of the same conceptual issues being discussed here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

About your primary question: I'd definitely go with `Answer...` whenever I have the possibility to do so. As you can pass on an array to a varargs parameter, but not varargs to an array parameter, varargs is the better option IMO.

### Other comments

#### Naming

```
private boolean isCorrect;
```

It is convention to not prefix boolean fields with `is`. The name of the method should be `is` + variable name with upper case starting letter, so:

```
public boolean isCorrect() {
    return correct;
}
```

#### final keyword

It is good practice to mark all possible fields with `final`, this applies in your case to:

```
private final String answer;
private final boolean correct; // note the name change
```

and in the `Question` class:

```
private final String question;
private final Answer[] answers;
```

#### Mutability

This code might seem harmless to you:

```
public Question(String question, Answer... answers) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}

public Answer[] getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}
```

But the fact is, this is slightly dangerous. Although your `Answer` class is immutable, this is not. Imagine the following code:

```
Question questionA = new Question("Do chickens fly?",
     new Answer("Yes", true),
     new Answer("No", false));
questionA.getAnswers()[0] = null;
questionA.getAnswers()[1] = new Answer("Always right", true);
```

Whoops, now we've cleared one answer and changed the other!

Solution: Make array copies using `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
public Question(String question, Answer... answers) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = Arrays.copyOf(answers, answers.length);
}

public Answer[] getAnswers() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(answers, answers.length);
}
```

#### Possible extension: Make it a `score`

Your classes supports multiple answers to be correct, that is nicely done. But what if one answer is still "better" than the other? My suggestion is that you use a `int` or a `float` for `score` instead of a `boolean correct`.

#### Java 8

If you have Java 8 available, your `isCorrect(String answer)` method can be improved:

```
public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
    return Arrays.stream(answers).anyMatch(a -> a.getAnswer().equals(answer));
}
```

The same can of course be applied to your `isCorrectIgnoreCase` method:

```
public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
    return Arrays.stream(answers).anyMatch(a -> a.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer));
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for marking the fields `final`?  Is it to make the class immutable?

Comment: @BrianJ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java

Answer (score 6):

## Brackets

I know brackets can be optional, but I would suggest you to use them since the following snippets from your code is hard to read :

> ```
>      for(Answer tempAnswer : answers)
>         if(tempAnswer.getAnswer().equals(answer) && tempAnswer.isCorrect())
>             return true;
> ```

Instead I would suggest this :

```
    for (Answer tempAnswer : answers) {
        if (tempAnswer.getAnswer().equals(answer) && tempAnswer.isCorrect()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Note: This is kind of preference choice. I find it a best practices to always use brackets since it can prevents error and make things more clear, but some people disagree on this.

## Answer and question

There is a small problem with your design at the moment, I don't have an obligation to mark an answer as the correct answer. If would create a new `Question` with only answer that provide the option `boolean isCorrect` as false, I would loop forever. See this example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question questionA = new Question("Do chickens fly?", new Answer("Yes",
            false), new Answer("No", false));
    System.out.println(questionA.getQuestion());

    while (true) {
        if (questionA.isCorrectIgnoreCase(scanner.nextLine())) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("No, that is incorrect. Please try again.");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Correct.");
}
```

One solution to prevent is to specify the correct answer as a parameter to the `Question` constructor or check in the constructor that at least one answer as the `isCorrect` equal to `true`. If there is no correct answer than just throw an exception.

One other things is, I have no obligation to pass an `Answer` to the question. You should check for this too.